# Background plane appears in front on certain angles

Tags: 3d-view, image

So The 2d plane behind appears in front of my other plane that is in front of it at certain angles, like on the photos below.

How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: i cannot even see your 2nd plane...!? can you make some arrows to make it clear?

Comment: Sounds like alpha blend VS. alpha hashed for blend method in the material settings.